# XMLWriter vs XMLDictionaryWriter

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

What's the difference between `XMLWriter` and `XMLDictionaryWriter`?  In which cases is each one generally used?

Comment: I like XMLDictionaryWriter's description on MSDN: *An abstract class that the derives from to do serialization and deserialization.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) is an abstract class of which [`XmlDictionaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) is one of the classes that inherits from it and is itself an abstract class.

I am taking a stab in the dark that you want to use it with the [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or with de/serialization in general. The `XmlDictionaryWriter` is the base class used by WCF to do its de/serialization.

From that I would deduce that there must be some performance tuning in the `XmlDictionaryWriter` to make it more performant with WCF de/serialization tasks. In fact if you call the [`WriteObject(Stream, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908459(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`WriteObject(XmlWriter, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908203(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908604(v=vs.110).aspx) methods it will create an `XmlDictionaryWriter` for you

```c#
public virtual void WriteObject(Stream stream, object graph)
{
    CheckNull(stream, "stream");
    XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false);
    this.WriteObject(writer, graph);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) is an abstract class used for writing XML documents in a forward-only manner. You use the static `Create` method to create concrete implementations of the class for use. This method of creating XML documents is useful when you need to quickly create arbitrary XML for whatever use.

[XmlDictionaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionarywriter.aspx) is an abstract class used for serialization and deserialization of objects to and from XML. From what I understand, it is used in WCF for serializing objects for moving across the wire. `XmlDictionaryWriter` can serialize using binary, text or MTOM formats. I would expect you would only use this class if you were specifically needing custom (de)serialization for use over WCF. See also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Serialization_in_WCF.aspx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The info about serialization (specifically, MTOM) is really helpful. Thanks!