# How can I set up an XmlWriter with the same settings as XmlDictionaryWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I'm currently using

```
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
XmlDictionaryWriter xdw = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(filestream, Encoding.UTF8);
dcs.WriteObject(xdw, obj);
```

In order to write out XML, I've heard good things about the WCF DataContractSerializer in terms of it's performance, and ability to provide forwards compatibility.

However, it's impossible to pass in settings to XmlDictionaryWriter.

I don't 100% understand the differences between XmlDictionaryWriter and a normal XmlWriter with custom settings, and it's impossible to tweak the settings of XmlDictionaryWriter as far as I'm aware.

So what are the differences between XmlDictionaryWriter and XmlWriter (yes one is a super class, but I'm talking concretely, vs `var XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filestream, settings);`)

And what settings can I use in order to imitate XmlDictionaryWriter as close as possible, except for having indentation set to true?

I've currently got

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                IndentChars = "    "
            };
```

As my settings for the XmlWriter, whereas XmlDictionaryWriter appears to have null Settings.  (`XmlDictionaryWriter.Settings` is both null and readonly, so that's a bust.)

My end goal is to have formatted XML, so maybe if the changes aren't too severe I can just use a hand created XmlWriter anyway.

Comparing the two using NUnit results in

`XmlDictionaryWriter`:

```
"<Party xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HeliSTATS.Test\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Guests><Larry><Age>12</Age><Friend><Name>John</Name></Friend></Larry><Larry><Age>15</Age><Friend><Name>Mason</Name></Friend></Larry></Guests></Party>"
```

`XmlWriter`:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<Party xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HeliSTATS.Test\">\r\n    <Guests>\r\n        <Larry>\r\n            <Age>12</Age>\r\n            <Friend>\r\n                <Name>John</Name>\r\n            </Friend>\r\n        </Larry>\r\n        <Larry>\r\n            <Age>15</Age>\r\n            <Friend>\r\n                <Name>Mason</Name>\r\n            </Friend>\r\n        </Larry>\r\n    </Guests>\r\n</Party>"
```

Comment: Have you considered ditching them both and using the more modern XDocument, XElement, and XAttribute classes from Linq?  Also do you have requirements for WCF instead of using WebApi2 and Rest?  WebApi2 respects content type headers, so will give XML to anyone who asks for it, or json to anyone who asks for it.

Comment: I wasn't aware. I'll look into it. I was drawn to DataContractSerializer due to explicit annotations and working without being public properties.

Comment: WebApi2 and Rest requires people to write there own interfaces to the results, but WebApi2 is pretty slick in building them, you can annotate your entities, easily do middle ware, and easily test them in PostMan etc.  This is how I prefer to do things.  I make an API, then I make a class library that is the "Client" that calls that Api, or I have a JS layer in Angular or Vue that calls the API via Ajax requests.  Almost every modern api made today is REST.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm using this for some super simple configs at the moment, which is why I'm caring about indentation, about limiting visibility modifiers. I'm not sure how suitable stuff designed for REST will be, but DCS mostly seems fine.

Comment: I've had a quick read over, I can see how it could be useful for transformation, or bulk xml processing. But it seems almost too flexible to me. I prefer the XML as Code/Classes approach since it feel's more like a schema, and makes it easier to validate IMO. But I can see where LINQ would be handy for some extremely dynamic XML, or even JSON.

Comment: For large xml files I would stick with XmlWriter so you can save small pieces of the file at one time.  I combine the XmlWriter and XDocument by using the XmlWriter writer.WriteRaw(string).  Then Take may XElement object and convert to a string object.ToString().  In a few case at top of Xml I have to use StartElement and EndElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually asking a few separate questions:

1. *What is the differences between `XmlDictionaryWriter` and `XmlWriter`?*

   This question is addressed in *[XMLWriter vs XMLDictionaryWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3604123/3744182)* with answers by [Bronumski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227200/bronumski) and [Mike McCaughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan).  The conclusion is that `XmlDictionaryWriter` is used

   - For performance (though we don't know for sure), and
   - As an abstract base class for XML, Binary and MTOM serialization of data contracts.

   In addition, some functionality of `DataContractSerializer` only works with `XmlDictionaryWriter`.  E.g. if you need to serialize an object using a [custom `DataContractResolver`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2009/06/05/configuring-known-types-dynamically-introducing-the-datacontractresolver/) you will need to use [`DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter, Object, DataContractResolver)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd438221.aspx) because there is no overload of [`WriteObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx#Methods) that takes both an `XmlWriter` and a `DataContractResolver`.
2. *How can I use `XmlDictionaryWriter` and also control `XmlWriterSettings`?*

   If you are sure you need to use `XmlDictionaryWriter` (for performance reasons, or because you need to use a `DataContractResolver`) then you can construct one that wraps a pre-existing `XmlWriter` by using [`XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(XmlWriter)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionarywriter.createdictionarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx).
3. *What settings can I use in order to imitate `XmlDictionaryWriter` with `XmlWriter` as closely as possible while still indenting?*

   You don't.  You use the one you need, and if you need the functionality of both, create a wrapped `XmlWriter` as shown above.

Putting all of the above together, the following extension methods can be used to serialize with both `XmlDictionaryWriter` and optional `XmlWriterSettings`:

```
public static partial class DataContractSerializerExtensions
{
    public static string ToContractXml<T>(this T obj, DataContractSerializer serializer = null, XmlWriterSettings settings = null, DataContractResolver resolver = null)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(obj == null ? typeof(T) : obj.GetType());
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding((settings == null ? null : settings.Encoding) ?? Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj, resolver);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static void WriteObject(this DataContractSerializer serializer, Stream stream, object obj, XmlWriterSettings settings, DataContractResolver resolver = null)
    {
        if (serializer == null || stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        // If settings are specified create a wrapped dictionary writer, else create a text writer directly.
        if (settings == null)
        {
            // Let caller close the stream
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj, resolver);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj, resolver);
            }
        }
    }

    static void WriteObject(this DataContractSerializer serializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object obj, DataContractResolver resolver)
    {
        if (serializer == null || xmlWriter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var xmlDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(xmlWriter))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(xmlDictionaryWriter, obj, resolver);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, profile `WriteObject()` with and without `XmlWriterSettings` to determine the performance impact of using a wrapped `XmlWriter`.